# What free online or self install tools is best to make 3d Logo

Tags: logo, 3d, information-graphics, graphic-styles

Does anyone knowx what is the best and easiest tool to start creating similar kind of square/round logo raised in a 45 degree platform thats comes with shadow shown in this example image.

[image]

---

I managed to make the angle of the image, as for the darker red, how do i raise it nicely.  I'm not use to inkscape, i'm trying to paste multiple layer on top to fill the gap, but i guess that's not the correct way.  As you can see, when i paste multiple layer, it doesn't blend in nicely.  Am I doing it correctly by adding multiple layer to fill in the gap ?

[image]

---

### Solutions and Result

Thank you all that help providing guidance and instruction.  I finally made it :)

[image]

Comment: You likely wouldn't need actual 3d software for such simple shapes. You could use a vector image editor, such as Inkscape (which is free).

Comment: You can create this using just about anything, including CSS

Comment: @ZachSaucier any example will be very much appreciated

Comment: Thank you all.  I finally made it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case seems to be finished, but here's still something. The isometric view of a simple button can be made without isometric grid, no matter the grid makes drawing and placing items easier when consistent sizes and distances are needed.

[image]

1. A rounded square and the shape on the button are inserted. It's useful to convert both of them to paths if path effects or node edits are needed later. In this case The rounded square gets some edits later, the A could as well stay as text, but both got Path > Object to path in the same time.
2. Both items are selected and Object > Transform > Rotate > 45 degrees is applied - that's the 45 degrees you mentioned in the question.
3. From engineering drawing theory one could pick that isometric view needs the already shown 45 degrees rotation and vertical squeezing to 57,7% (an irrational number, cannot be presented exactly with numbers, but 0,1% resolution is visually good enough). Both items are selected and to infao panel is typed  H = 57,7%. The width stays 100% - no proportionality locking!

To drawthe apparent extrusion exactly the left and right ends of the red shape both need a node. They can be inserted exactly with the node tool if there's path crossings in right places and there's snap to path crossings = ON. In image 4 a strictly horizontal line (hold Ctrl-key) is drawn with the pen so that it snaps with the center of the red shape. As well the items can be aligned.

5. The line is sent to back and the wanted 2 new nodes are inserted to the red shape by double-clicking with the node tool.

[image]

6. The red shape is duplicated. The duplicate is in my example colored to grey to make it clearly visible as separate item. The duplicate is sent to back and moved downwards by ticking with the down-arrow key. As well it cocould be moved with the mouse and then aligned to  be sure it's placed straight downwards from the red shape.
7. A rectangle is drawn  between the extreme left and right nodes. Those nodes were inserted to become able to draw the rectangle exactly (by having also snappings in use). The rectangle is colored temporarily to blue only to show it clearly here.
8. The rectangle and the bottom grey shape are combined to one with Path > Union. The result must be sent to back.

[image]

9. The united grey shape is sent to back
10. Another duplicate of the red shape is made, colored to black, sent to back and moved a little to the right.
11. The button with deep black shadow is now done, but in some cases people may want more details. Here are some rough, but easy to draw embellishments which do not need any effects nor anything which is available in Adobe's programs or 3D applications, but not in Inkscape:

- the shadow is blurry. Actually there's 2 differently placed and differently blurred black shapes with different opacities to make the shadow intensified near the button.
- the grey extrusion has got gradient fill to imitate 3D shading
- the white shape on the button has got very slight gradient to make it look metallic. The shape itself looks debossed because there's a slightly moved dark red copy which imitates the shadow on the pressed vertical surface.
- the red shape has got something which resembles a bevel. it's a stroke with gradient fill. The grey part also has a stroke to keep the sizes equal

Comment: This is very helpful tricks, thanks @oneprivate

Answer (score 4):

The example graphic isn't at a 45° angle, it's 30°.

These are quite simple designs, and you wouldn't need actual 3D software to create something like this. You could use 2D vector software. Something like Illustrator, CorelDraw, Affinity Designer, or Inkscape, etc.

Here's an example made using Inkscape (which is free and Open Source). First I drew the icon, and the rounded corner square, and grouped these. Then I used the built-in axonometric grid, which I set to 30° to create an isometric grid, added a Perspective Envelope path effect, and distorted it to fit the grid. The shadow and darker red and grey shadow pieces are just duplicates of the lighter red square filled a different colour.

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what i'm looking for.  Thank you very much